# Hiding/displaying button based on conditions and issues with basic queries

Tags: php, html, css

I am currently in mid development of a social networking site. I am trying to hide and display buttons based on the conditions set but I am coming across difficulties before that. At the moment, my mind just cannot process how to specify this into code.

I have an `Add to Favourites` which is visible on pages besides the profile page of the user logged in. Let's assume I am logged in as Freddy, and I go to Alice's profile page, where the button is visible, and the actions specified for the button work, the data is sent to the database. However, I am trying to specify that once a user is already in the logged in users favourites, the `Add to Favourites` button will then be replaced by `Remove from Favourites`.

I am unable to first of all, specify that the user can only favourite the user once, at the moment, when `Add to Favourites` is clicked on any profile, the database will update will as many rows, when Freddy should only be allowed to favourite Alice once.

This is what I have tried at the moment to allow the user to only be favourited once:

```
 <?php
// code to process a favourite request
if (isset($_POST['addfriend'])) { 
    $fav_request    = $_POST['addfriend'];
    $favourited_who = $user; // u variable
    $favourited_by  = $username; // logged in user
    /*
    * Need to check that the user who is logged in, hasnt already got the $user in there favs
    */

    // Step 1: Get all the favourites of the logged in user...
    $q = mysqli_query ($connect, "SELECT * FROM favourites");
        while ($r_query = mysqli_fetch_array($q)) {
            $db_fav_who = $r_query['favourited_who'];
            $db_fav_by = $r_query['favourited_by'];
    // Step 2: Check whether the profile page the user is viewing, isnt already in there favourites...



    // Check: See if $user isn't already in there favourites.
    if ($db_fav_by == $username){ // check to see which users favourites we are checking
        // if the user already exists in the logged in users favourites, then display remove from favourites button.
        if ($db_fav_who == $user){
            echo "<div class='edit_profile'>
                <input type='submit' class='btn btn-info' name='remfriend' value='Remove from Favourites'>
            </div";
            }
        }
        }// while loop closed
    if ($user != $username) { // Check: See user isnt favouriting themself.
        $favourite_user = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO favourites VALUES ('', '$favourited_who', '$favourited_by')");
        echo "done ";
    }
} // if isset closed
?>
```

At the moment, there are two buttons which are visible when going onto anyone's (besides your own) profile page:

```
<div class="edit-profile">
<?php 
    if ($user == $username){
    // dont display buttons
    }else { ?>
        <form action="" method="post">
        <?php
         echo  "
            <input type='submit' class='btn btn-info' name='sendmsg' value='Send Message'/>
            <input type='submit' class='btn btn-info' name='addfriend' value='Add to Favourites'>
        </form>";
    }
    ?> 
</div>
```

**Note**: `$user` is the variable to get the u variable in the url. `$username` is the session variable for the logged in user.

How can I get the `Add to Favourites` button to only be visible if he/she is not in the logged in users variable? and if they are, how can I get the `Remove from Favourites` button to be visible instead of the `Add to Favourites` button?

Comment: Why isnt the opening <form> brace inside the echo?

Comment: Also, are you talking about the actual display or are you asking why your php conditions don't return as intended?

Comment: @Tony - Primarily, I need to specify conditions which do not allow the same `$user` to be Favorited more than once by the user logged in `$username`. My attempts to accomplish this are shown above, but the logged in user is able to add the same person to there favourites more than once.

Comment: If you want a live update when the user clicks the button you are going to have to use Javascript. PHP is server based, meaning any changes to your page will not be made until the entire page is refreshed.